# How to fetch the first comment date of users in comments table

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

have a comments table and need to get the first comment date (first inserted record) of each users in the table.

Output will be :

```
user_id   first_comment_date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min()` try

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(comment_date) 
FROM commentstable 
GROUP BY user_id;
```